# LinkedServer "Out of memory while reading tuples" issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

We have set up linked server for accessing our application database "PostgreSQL" in SQL Server 2012.

I am getting the following error while just storing data from particular linked server into one of the temporary tables. I also tried storing in the physical table as well but same error.

Query:

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#quotestpremium') is not null drop table tempdb..#quotestpremium
Select * into tempdb..#quotestpremium from
(Select * from [RWPRODMAIN].[dwh001].[apps_u001].quotestpremium)a
go
```

Error:

```
**Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "RWPRODMAIN" returned message "Out of memory while reading tuples.".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "RWPRODMAIN" reported an error. The provider ran out of memory.
Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
Cannot open the table ""dwh001"."apps_u001"."quotespremium"" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "RWPRODMAIN".**
```

This table has 453K records.

Please share your experience if you have dealing with a similar issue.

Comment: This will get closed as off-topic on SO.  But you need more details for when it gets moved to a better location.  Specifically the server memory stats, the exact ODBC driver you are using, whether this happens again immediately after restarting SQL Server, and any errors in the SQL Log.

Comment: After restarting SQL Server it does look better. It created a temp table with 450K+ records. Does it make any sense or help to get above any of the above details.

Comment: 3rd party ODBC drivers and OleDb drivers are notorious for leaking memory, and SQL Server will normally stay up for weeks or months between restarts.  That's a very bad combination.

Answer (score 1):

> After restarting SQL Server it does look better. It created a temp table with 450K+ records. Does it make any sense or help to get above any of the above details

3rd party ODBC drivers and Ole Db providers are notorious for leaking memory, and SQL Server will normally stay up for weeks or months between restarts.  That's a very bad combination.  It's generally better to use the 3rd party drivers in an SSIS package or other short-lived external program, and avoid loading them in SQL Server's address space.

Alternatively you could periodically restart SQL Server as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `openquery()` instead of four part naming. Openquery is working in my case (Postgresql linked in mssql).  I have not needed a server restart.